# Unable to runserver when I close my SSH connection with AWS EC2

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2

Hope anyone with these areas of expertise can help me.

Basically, I am trying to run my Django project inside the EC2 instance in Amazon Web Service. I have placed the files and tried to run the server with

```
python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

The steps I used to configure my EC2 is by referring to this website: **https://medium.com/saarthi-ai/ec2apachedjango-838e3f6014ab**. I followed all the steps and I was able to deploy my project.

However, once I close my SSH connection, I won't be able to access the website anymore. Is there a solution to this?

Regards,
YX

Answer (score 0):

When you exit(close connection) from **SSH**. It will close all user activity which are running on.

So you need to *`deploy`* your **`Django`** project on server with specified `port`. So project have accessible anytime from any where as per defined policy.

Please follow the following link to deploy your django project on ec2.

> you need to configure **`Gunicorn`** with **`Nginx`** to host your
>   project on **EC2**
>
> https://www.pythoncircle.com/post/235/how-to-setup-django-app-on-ec2-instance-aws/

If you have  experienced person on `AWS` than you need to follow following instruction.

> https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/deploy-python-application/

Thanks